# Photo compare c#

Tags: c#, image, compare, kinect

I'm using a kinect to take photos and then I'm trying to compare them , The photos will be stored in directories and read in as filestreams , I need to compare the images and decide if they are the same with a pretty high error tolerance to account for diff backgrounds etc its more about the users pose , I'm just wondering if anyone has any tips where to look as I cant find anything

Thanks all

Comment: Down-voted. I was able to find a large number of SO posts and other articles with a simple google search: "photo comparison c#". I'd suggest you start there and then post a new question if you are looking for help with a particular algorithm or approach.

Comment: I've done that already and found loads of stuff , finding photo comparison isnt the problem , I'm looking for an algorithm/approach that offers a reliable level of error tolerance

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment, not an answer because it's just a general pointer. You might want to look at [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/). It is "an open source C# framework designed for developers and researchers in the fields of Computer Vision and Artificial Intelligence - image processing, neural networks, genetic algorithms, fuzzy logic, machine learning, robotics, etc."

Comment: You might also want to look into the [.Net wrapper](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) for [ImageMagick Compare](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php). On another note, to get an idea of how complicated the human form recognition aspect is, check out some of the materials [here](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=145347).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is more complicated than you might think at first.

If you are simply comparing 2 images and considering them the same if they are within an error tolerance this is not a reliable way to detect the same pose.

If I am on a black background and perform two different poses, they would have a relatively low 'difference' as the majority of pixels in both images are black.  If I perform the same pose on a patterned background and then on a black background, the 'difference' between the two would be high dispite the pose being the same.

I think the correct approach would be to look for the extremities (hands, feet etc) and try to compare the position of those. I suspect that sampling each image in its entirety will not be accurate enough.

Comment: If "its more about the user pose" then you should compare the skeleton data instead of user image.